# How to let user can only read files?

Tags: permissions, users, scp, sftp

I have some new files to release every day.

My coworker needs to sftp/scp to my Linux server to copy these files.

I don't want him to do any file delete/move/execution...etc, the only thing he can do should be copied (scp/sftp) the files back.

The best is he can't switch directories.

Any method to do this?

Comment: The easy way is the restricted shell. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Restricted-Shell.html

Comment: @K-att- I think you should expand this to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by creating a user and a group with the necessary permissions to just read the files or folder.

Here is an example of how to achieve read-only access via scp (ssh) to a folder on a Linux server.

```
useradd <USERNAME> # no need to create a home directory, so we can skip --create-home

groupadd <GROUPNAME> # create the group that will have read-only-access to the folder
```

Now add the created user to the created group

```
usermod -aG <GROUPNAME> <USERNAME>
```

Now create the folder somewhere on your system that the user should have access to:

```
mkdir <FOLDERNAME> -m rwxr-x-r
```

Now change the group of that folder to the created group with

```
chgrp <GROUPNAME> </PATH/TO/FOLDER>
```

Now, when you add files in that folder, make sure that they are also owned by the created group with the necessary permissions:

```
chmod 744 <FILENAME> 
chgrp <GROUPNAME> <PATH/TO/FILE>
```

With that, the user should be able to access the folder via scp like this:

```
scp -r user@<IP>:/path/to/folder /local/path/
```

**EDIT**
Adding a group with 744 permission can be skipped, since the default permissions for others are already 744 (read-only). Thanks @symcbean for pointing that out.

Comment: What's to keep the user from running `scp user@<IP>:/etc/passwd .`. Replace `/etc/passwd` with any other file that you might want protected. I would suggest using `command=` in the user's .ssh/authorized keys to limit access.

Comment: If the permissions are 0744 than prvisioning a group to have read-only permissions is a bit redundant since OTHER users already have read-only permission.

Comment: @symcbean is right, this flew over my head while working out my example. Provisioning a group is redundant in that case.